# UILabel is starting from vertical center

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Hi I have a UILabel being added from my code. I have set it as

```
let lb3 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: summaryView.frame.width - 20, height: 120))

        lb3.text = "This is body of the message. This is body of the message. This is body of the message. This is body of the message."
        lb3.textAlignment   = .left
        lb3.numberOfLines   = 10
        lb3.lineBreakMode   = .byWordWrapping
        lb3.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        lb3.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
```

Total height of `lb3` is 120 as per snippet
so upper left corner is at coordinate (0, 0)
and bottom right coordinate at (x=width, 120)
`lb3` is starting from `(0, 60)` assuming this view starts from `(0, 0)` but I want `lb3` to start from `(0, 0)` itself not from its vertical center.

I added lb3 in following manner as this is my view hierarchy

```
summaryView.addSubview(lb3)
v.addSubview(summaryView)
self.view.addSubview(v)
```

Comment: The Label's container view may have 60px vertical content offset. Please check the container view.

Comment: Show how do you add the `lb3` in the view controller.

Comment: @maddy Though I made changes as you pointed now have a look if you can understand

Comment: @YunCHEN is it set on its own? Bcz I have not set it explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is simply not how UILabels work. Their text is always vertically centered within the height of the label. You are setting the label to be much taller than its text requires, so there is space above the text and below the text.

The usual alternative is to make a UILabel that sets its own height just sufficiently to contain its text (easy to do); that way, the text starts at the top left of the label and fills the label perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, the text inside a `UILabel` will always be vertically centered. A good workaround for you issue would be:

```
var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: summaryView.frame.width - 20, height: 120)
let lb3 = UILabel(frame: frame)
lb3.text = "This is body of the message. This is body of the message. This is body of the message. This is body of the message."
lb3.textAlignment   = .left
lb3.numberOfLines   = 10
lb3.lineBreakMode   = .byWordWrapping
lb3.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
lb3.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .light)
lb3.sizeToFit()
frame.size.height = lb3.frame.size.height
lb3.frame = frame
```